# What is the difference between setting properties in a constructor vs in the properties getter?

Tags: polymer-2.x

In Polymer 2 docs, they show using the constructor to set this.owner = "daniel" and then later they show how to set properties using static get properties().

In JSConsole, I can use myelement.owner and myelement.prop1, and if I dir(myelement) I can see both owner and prop1 there... so what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, As regards to functionality, both achieve the same.

- Initialize a class variable

The timeline favors the constructor initialized variable really.

However, since you initialize **owner** in the CTOR, you can not fetch it via `myElement.properties`.

the advantage of using the static method may be that, you need not create an element `<my-element>` from class `myElement` to fetch any property you defined inside the static method.

> Try logging `myElement.properties` - and see that you can not find owner listed. you will however find prop1 there.

However, for you to get the value of **owner**, you essentially need to instantiate the class `myElement` or connect an element `<my-element>` to the DOM

> Try logging `myElement.owner` - this should return undefined
>
> Try logging `new myElement().owner` - this should fetch daniel